# OSMdroid - zoom 17 with map tiles from zoom 16?

Tags: android, zooming, osmdroid

I have implemented offline map tiles 7 - 16 in my application. But zoom 16 is still quite from a distance and I don't have access for tiles level 17. Is there any way how to zoom to level 17, while using tiles 16? This makes street name readable than in level 16.

So the questions is: I need to have zoom 17 with tiles from zoom 16. Is it possible, and how?

Thx for any suffestions

Answer (score 0):

OSMdroid doesn't allow zooming by stretching the tiles.

If you are using `mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.ANY_BUILT_IN_ONLINE_SOURCE);`, the use of `mapView.getController().setZoom(n);` will automatically download the tiles that appear on the `MapView` for this level of zoom (should this level be in the defined range of this provider). Maybe a solution would be to save these tiles for a future offline usage.

If you are using offline tiles only, you either have to:

- store the tiles corresponding to the desired level of zoom
- or implement your own image stretching routine in your offline tiles provider
- or precompute a set of stretched tiles based on the level 16 that you store as level 17 on your device

Comment: And how to precompute tiles 16 to fit into 17?